# Firebase Functions в swift не возвращает ничего при отсутствии интернета

Tags: swift, firebase

Есть Функция, которая срабатывает после авторизации AccountKit, она запускает Функцию Firebase для проверки токена на Facebook и возвращает userId если всё подтверждается, а заодно и регистрирует пользователя если он еще не был зареген.

Проблема в том, что при включенном интернете всё отрабатывает без проблем, но стоит интернету пропасть, Firebase функция не возвращает ничего, а хотелось бы, чтобы она возвращала ошибку а`ля No internet connection или хоть что-нибудь за что можно было бы зацепиться.

Продолжительные гугления и копания в APIReference не дали результатов. Неужели в самом деле call firebase функции не умеет ничего возвращать в таких случаях?

```
func checkUserCredentials(phoneNumber: String, FBId: String, Token: String)
{
    functions.httpsCallable("checkUserCredentials").call(["phone":"\(phoneNumber)", "FBId":"\(FBId)", "Token":"\(Token)"])
    {   (result, error) in

        if let error = error as NSError?
        {
            print("\(error)")
            if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain
            {
                let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                let message = error.localizedDescription
                print ("\(String(describing: code)) -  \(message)")
            }
        }

        if let userDoc = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["userID"] as? String
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "StartTheApp", sender: self) })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По идее, в замыкании у Вас есть error, т.е. выдача ошибки предусмотрена параметрами вызываемой функции. Смотрите какой ответ у error и обрабатывайте его?

Comment: По идее конечно да, но только в error попадают ошибки связанные с выполнением функции на сервере. Если интернет подключения нет, то весь completion блок вообще не выполняется. В этом то собственно и проблема...

Comment: Тогда можно сделать проверку доступности сервера Firebase через URLSession и, соотвественно, вызывать эту функцию или показывать ошибку.

Comment: Ну да. Костыльно правда получается, но вариант. Хотелось бы конечно без лишних ступеней, но видимо не получится =)

Comment: Видимо обработка ошибок сетевого уровня оставлена на усмотрение разработчика. А точно замыкание не выполняется, если нет подключения? Это достаточно долгий процесс (попытка подключения), попробуйте подождать 5 минут.

Comment: И правда ведь) Подождал несколько минут и вернулась сетевая ошибка. Ёлки-палки, столько времени потратил, а надо было просто подождать. Спасибо большое! Надо теперь попробовать найти где ставить значение timeout чтобы пользователя в заблуждение не вводить индикатором подключения.

Comment: Рад, что помог )